# Using onCheckedChanged with PopupControlExtender and want to prevent popup when unchecking

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am still reasonably new to this and have tried to find an answer, so hopefully I am not repeating this.

I am using ASP.NET and have a checkbox control that brings up a popup box when it's changed, using the onCheckedChanged method. This popup box has some info in it and a 'Close' button which successfully closes the popup.

What I want is to prevent the popup appearing if the checkbox is being unchecked. I currently have the onCheckedChanged calling a code behind method which cancels the extender call if the control is not checked, but the popup quickly appears before it is closed. How can I prevent it this?

This is the appropriate page code:

```
        <div class="row" id="divDDMandate" runat="server">

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDDMandate" Width="20px" Visible="true" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                 OnCheckedChanged="clientchkDDMandateChanged(this);" on  />        
                <asp:Literal ID="ltlDDMandate" runat="server">Direct Debit Mandate (by post)</asp:Literal>

            <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="chkDDMandate_PopupControlExtender" runat="server" 
                DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="true" PopupControlID="PanelDDMandateDownload"
                TargetControlID="chkDDMandate"
                Position="Bottom" OffsetX="-20" OffsetY="10" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

...and this is my code behind method:

```
        protected void chkDDMandateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Cancel the panel if unchecking
        if ((!chkDDMandate.Checked) && chkDDMandate_PopupControlExtender.Enabled)
        {
            chkDDMandate_PopupControlExtender.Cancel();
        }
    }
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `AutoPostBack="true"` from the chkDDMandate checkbox and add script below after the ScriptManager control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        var extender = $find("<%= chkDDMandate_PopupControlExtender.ClientID %>");
        extender.remove_showing(onPopupShowing);
        extender.add_showing(onPopupShowing);
    }

    function onPopupShowing(sender, args) {
        var checkBoxChecked = $get("<%= chkDDMandate.ClientID %>").checked;
        args.set_cancel(!checkBoxChecked);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Yuriy, this has got me closer! I new it needed an event handler somewhere, but I'm new to the javascript. The issue now is that the popup is disabled completely until the next page refresh. I check/uncheck and nothing more happens after the first run of the handler..

Comment: Try to move focus out of the checkbox (i.e. click anywhere on a page). I believe that out of the box popup control shows popup when control got a focus.

Answer (score 0):

After Yuriy provided me with the event handler, I had to resort to using hidden fields to keep track of the visibility of the popup and the checkbox.

This was because I didn't want the popup to appear when the tick was being removed and the fact that the onClick method used the setting the checkbox control was being set to, whereas the onShowing method was using the current visible setting of the control. I had to use the hidden fields to keep the visibilty settings and update them at the time I wanted.

I'm surprised that the _visible property of the popup extender was always set to 'false', so I couldn't use that either.

This may be a bit of a hack, but this is my current javascript code for anyone that is interested:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

     function pageLoad() {
     // Attach an event handler for over-riding the showing Popup.
         var extender = $find("PopupControlExtenderBehaviorID");
         extender.remove_showing(onPopupShowing);
         extender.add_showing(onPopupShowing);

     // Initialise the hidden fields based on the page status after refresh.
         var hfPopup = $get("ctl00_body_PopupVisibleID");
         var hfCheckbox = $get("ctl00_body_CheckboxChecked");

     // Popup will always be hidden on page refresh
         hfPopup.value = "Hidden";
         hfCheckbox.value = $get("ctl00_body_chkDDMandate").checked;
     }  

     function onPopupShowing(sender, args) {
        // This function will over-ride the Popup showing if applicable.
         var popupVisible = $get("ctl00_body_PopupVisibleID");
         var checkboxChecked = $get("ctl00_body_CheckboxChecked");

        // If Popup hidden and 'tick' being taken out of the Checkbox, don't show the Popup.
         if (popupVisible.value == "Hidden" && checkboxChecked.value == "true") {
             args.set_cancel(true);
         }
         else if (popupVisible.value == "Hidden") {
            popupVisible.value = "Visible";
            }
            else {popupVisible.value = "Hidden";}

     }

    function OnClientClickCheck(o) {
        // This function will set the Hidden field value of Checkbox.
        // This is because when the OnClick method reads the control checkbox value it uses the value it's 
        // being set to; whereas, the onPopupShowing method uses the value it is currently displaying!
        var pce = $find('PopupControlExtenderBehaviorID');
        var checkboxChecked = $get("ctl00_body_CheckboxChecked");
        var isChecked = o.checked;

        if (isChecked) {
        // isChecked is what it is being changed to...
            checkboxChecked.value = "false";
        }
        else {
            checkboxChecked.value = "true";
        }
        pce.showPopup();
    }
</script>
```

Thanks for the help in getting here.